# Batch processing clip layer: " 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pendingFields' "

Tags: qgis

I am trying to clip many vector layers to a boundary by following the tutorial at http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/batch_processing.html

ie using Clip in the Processing Toolbox, then 'execute as batch process'. However, I recieve an error message -

> Algorithm Clip starting...
>    'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pendingFields'

but I don't know what that message means or how to fix it. Thanks for any help

EDIT: in the end I clipped the layers one by one through the 'Geoprocessing - Clip' menu. That worked, so now I suppose the issue is with the batch processing command rather than the shapefiles themselves.

Comment: It's a bug of the processing algorithm. Could you open a ticket in QGIS tracker?

Comment: Thanks, I've done that - Bug report #13270

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that bash didn't get the target layer.

I get the similar error when I run reprojection.

before the input layer was "A layer", the input is a string.
then I redo select from open layers. the quotation mark disappear.

it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

I've had the same problem. I solved it by using layers from file system instead of opened layers.

This is not very convenient but it can help !